# identificar marcador do mapa de sites terceiros

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, marker, marcadores

Existe algum método de 'rastreamento' de marcador do mapa (google maps) do site de terceiros?

Por exemplo: [neste site](http://pt.mygeoposition.com/) teria alguma maneira de rastrear esse marcador feito no mapa? Seria estilo uma varredura para utilizar a localização e a legenda que esse marcador carrega.

Pensei em usar o API do Google Maps mas não encontrei o que procurava ou não encontrei o artigo certo. Porque esse marcador pode variar para outros sites e então não posso fixar.

Alguma sugestão?